# Hosting an angular-fullstack Yeoman Site on IIS

Tags: iis, hosting, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I have a project built using the angular-fullstack generator for Yeoman. I would like to deploy this to a Windows Server running IIS. I have successfully generated the "dist" folder using Grunt and moved the "public" and "server" folders with files to my IIS box.

How do I configure my Windows Server to host my application? Do I need to have two IIS sites (one for "public" and one for "server")? Do I need to install grunt, bower, etc. on the Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to manually install grunt nor bower. Install locally the node components declared in package.json using the following comman:

```
npm install
```

The angular-fullstack generator creates a Node.js application, so all you have to do is run the server side application. Run `/server/app.js` with Node.js

You can check how to run Node applications inside IIS here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the application on [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) 
the do the right configuration for you web.config file I currently are able to run the application using the nodejs server but not in the iisnode applications because my web.config file still working correct I posted a question with more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608917/how-to-create-the-right-re-write-rules-for-web-config-on-iis-7-5-for-angular-ful)

Answer (score 0):

This is just to give you a hint to the way to a solution. It´s not a detailed step by step answer.

If alredy using Grunt, you can use [this grunt plugin](https://github.com/mrjackdavis/grunt-msdeploy/). 
It´s a wrapper of the msdeploy.exe command so you need to learn about that [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106(v=ws.10).aspx).

Before all of this you need to install Web Deploy on your server. There are serveral strats and posts about this. I choosed using the [Remote Agent](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-remote-agent) way.

I manually create the website (don´t know how to do this remotely yet. Working on that. That´s why I found this question) before I deploy. Then I just sync directories in my computer (your /dist folder) and the path in the remote server.

This a piece of my Gruntfile.js with 2 examples defined in the `grunt.initConfig()`

'Backup' saves in a package (zip file) the current remote directory.
The second task called 'Oper' syncs your current build located on <%= yeoman.dist %>

```
msdeploy: {
    backup: {
        options: {
            verb: "sync",
            source: {
                dirPath: '<%= deploy.Config.basePathOper %><%=deploy.Oper.Web %>,computerName=<%=deploy.Config.computerName %>,username=<%=deploy.Config.username %>,password=<%= deploy.Config.password %>'
            },
            dest: {
                package: '<%= deploy.Config.basePathOper %>\\backups\\web_' + grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-ss") + '.zip,computerName=<%=deploy.Config.computerName %>,username=<%=deploy.Config.username %>,password=<%= deploy.Config.password %>'
            }
        }
    },
    Oper: {
        options: {
            verb: 'sync',
            source: {
                dirPath: process.cwd() + '\\<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            dest: {
                dirPath: '<%= deploy.Config.basePathOper %><%=deploy.Oper.Web %>,computerName=<%=deploy.Config.computerName %>,username=<%=deploy.Config.username %>,password=<%= deploy.Config.password %>'
            }
        }
    }
```

The task I created looks something like this

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', function (target) {
  if (target === 'Oper') {
      grunt.task.run([
      'msdeploy:backup',
      'msdeploy:Oper'
      ]);
  }
```

});

Don´t forget to load the plugin:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-msdeploy');
```